# C# Сравнение изображений без МО(НС)

Tags: c#, нейронные-сети, сравнение

Здравствует, пишу проект который должен проверить 2 изображения и сказать является ли картинка 1 картинкой 2.

Например картинка из мема 1 это картинка 2. 
Подскажите: возможно ли реализация этого без нейросети, или какую сеть придется использовать?

Comment: Нейросети больше рассчитаны на определённые задачи, например распознавание символа `s` или кота на изображении. Ещё интересует как именно вы хотите сравнивать изображения, попиксельно или, например, примитивами? Это будут конкретные образы или вообще всё подряд?

Comment: Меня интересует способ при котором программа сможет определить является ли изображение клоном даже если оно подрезано или немного изменено(яркость добавлена, небольшие искажения при оптимизации для интернета), на ум пришёл метод сверток из нейроситей, но понимая понимая что они нужны, как вы и сказали для определения объекта, я и задал вопрос о реализации без нейроситей. 1 изображения целевое, а второе или левое, или целевое но подрезанное

Comment: Так-то есть очень много алгоритмов для сравнения изображений, на хабре есть инфа, я уже не говорю про англоязычные топики. С нейросетями тоже придётся повозиться, взгляните в сторону `Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit`.

Comment: То есть первое изображение имеет разрешение 400х800, а второе например 400х720, но на них одно и тоже, что бы программа сравнила их выдала хотя бы что изображение 2 отличает от первого на `x` из `y`